# Undefined $_POST after xmlhttp request

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My code makes an xmlhttp request to a php file, sending an ID so that a record can be identified and deleted from the database. However, when performing the delete query, I'm get an error saying 'comicID' is undefined (the variable using the ID value sent by POST). I'm not sure how to make sure it is defined correctly. Currently, the error I'm getting back from error handling is: "No comic supplied." and the error I get when removing the ISSET section of code is: "Error. Pages in comic not deleted." As it stands, the delete query doesn't work.

Javascript:

```
function delComic()
        {
            var radioButtons = $("#listID input:radio[name='comicList']");
            var radioID = radioButtons.index(radioButtons.filter(':checked'));
            console.log(radioID);
            if (radioID < 0)
            {
                window.alert("You must select a comic before deleting.");
            }
            else
            {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "delCom.php?comicID="+radioID;

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {   
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        var message = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        loadComic();
                        window.alert(message);
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

        }
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["comicID"])) 
{
$comic = $_POST["comicID"];
$dir = 'comics/'.$comic.'/';

if (!file_exists($dir)) 
{
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
}

include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');

mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM serieslink WHERE comicID = '$comic'");
$query = ("DELETE FROM page WHERE comicID = '$comic'"); 
if (!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{
    echo ("Query1 error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    exit;
}
else
{
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
    {
        $dirHandle = opendir($dir);
        while($file = readdir($dirHandle))
        {
            if(!is_dir($file))
            {
                unlink("$dir"."$file");
            }
        }
        closedir($dirHandle);

        rmdir($dir);
        $query2 = ("DELETE FROM comic WHERE comicID = '$comic'");
        if (!mysqli_query($conn, $query2))
        {
            echo ("Query2 error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) 
            {
                echo ("The selected comic was successfully deleted.");
            }
            else
            {
                echo ("Error. Comic not deleted.");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error. Pages in comic not deleted.";
    }
}   
$conn->close();
}
else
{
$comic = null;
echo "No comic supplied";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it myself by accident. It turns out the error is that the program is halting at the point that it tries to delete all pages associated with a comic. When it is presented with an already empty comic, it tries to delete nonexistent records. Manually adding a page to the comic and THEN trying to delete the comic outright worked perfectly.

So basically, I just need error handling for empty comics.
Thanks for the pointers regarding POST, however.

Answer (score 2):

With POST you do your Ajax request different that with GET. The query string is an argument to the `send()` function rather than part of the url, and you leave off the `?`:

```
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "delCom.php";

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {   
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    var message = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    loadComic();
                    window.alert(message);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send("comicID="+radioID);
```

Edit:

You also really should urlencode the parameter values, if they can contain spaces, etc.  And to circumvent possible browser caching you can add a parameter with the time:

```
var d = new Date();
xmlhttp.send("comicID="+encodeURIComponent(radioID)+"&ts="+d.getTime());
```

There's no need to read that timestamp param on the server-side; its only to trick the browser.

Comment: I'm still getting 'No comic supplied' unfortunately.

Comment: @alex494 Only thing I can think of is browser caching. It could be still using an old cached version of the JS if its in an external JS file...you'll either have to clear the cache or request the JS file directly to get it to update..or if the JS was updated in the browser already, it could have cached previous Ajax requests...see the cache workaround I added. Supposedly POST requests aren't cached, but I don't think IE knows that.

Comment: Adding the bit you suggested in the send part has basically made the button do nothing, where before it was giving a dialogue, weirdly. I made sure to clear all caches before trying.

Comment: I also tried changing URI to URL (figured that might be a typo), same result.

Comment: @alex494 Try `var_dump ($_POST);` to see what is actually coming across.

Comment: Turns out you were correct about using POST over GET, but the major thing that solved the problem was my discovery that deleting all pages from comics with no pages to start with screws with the deletion process. Error handling on that section should smooth it over nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Change the three first lines to, and everything should work fine.

```
if (isset($_GET["comicID"])) 
{
$comic = $_GET["comicID"];
```

Comment: Nope, nothing changed.

Comment: @developerwjk Yes it will, you can still read GET variables specified in the URL, even if the request is a POST.

Comment: No, you're thinking of `$_REQUEST` which covers both GET and POST. `$_GET` is only for GET. (Ok, maybe if you put params in the querystring like a GET while technically doing a POST it would work, but I wouldn't count on it in production)

Comment: @developerwjk Try it!
test.php: **<?php
echo $_GET['test']; **

Send a POST-request to page.php?test=HELLO and the page will output HELLO

Comment: @developerwjk There is no reason it would ever fail, so I see no reason not to depend upon it. I've been using it for years. <form method="post" action="edit.php?id=123">
The $_GET['id'] will always be 123 in this case.

Comment: If you mix them it will fail for sure. If you have a form like `<form method='post' action='edit.php?id=123'> <input name='x' value='3' /></form>` in some browsers you will end up with parameters being stripped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71726/discussion-between-lshas-and-developerwjk).

Comment: The point is kind of moot here, I tried it and it didn't work.